# Find a word (substring) in a string based on random character position

Tags: algorithm

Let's say you have a string:

```
I like apples more than oranges.
```

And you get an `Int` as an input in the program, let's say 11.

Character no. 11 is the `l` in `apples`. Based on that number, what is the most efficient and elegant solution to get to `apples`?

As a reference, I am using `Kotlin`

Comment: Assuming the words are small and the sentence is long, go backwards until you hit a space, then forwards until you hit a space, and then slice out that substring. This will scale better if the sentence is very long.

Comment: Split into words, sum length+1 for each element until value >= input. That word will be the one required.

Comment: Make a list of all the indexes in the string where spaces occur. Binary search for the largest value less than the integer. To simplify edge cases, prepend [-1] and append [string.length] to the index list.

Comment: What ATOMP said, but also accept position 0 for start, last position for end, and any non-alpha character (like punctuation) for end of word.

Answer (score 0):

Simply start at the given index and loop backwards until you reach the stop sequence (space, period or either end of string), and repeat the same thing moving forwards.

Here's an implementation of how it would work using *Kotlin*:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val str = "I like apples more than oranges."
    
    println(findWord(str, 15))
}

fun findWord(str: String, index: Int):String {
    var fi = 0
    var li = str.length-1
    var i = index-1
    
    if(str[index] == ' ' || str[index] == '.')
        return "Invalid Index"
    
    while (i >= 0) {
        if(str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '.'){
            fi = i
            break
        }
        i--
    }
    
    i = index+1
    
    while (i <= str.length-1) {
        if(str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '.'){
            li = i
            break
        }
        i++
    }
    
    
    fi = if(fi==0 && (str[fi] != ' ' && str[fi] != '.'))fi else fi+1
    li = if(li==str.length-1 && (str[li] != ' ' && str[li] != '.'))li+1 else li
    
    return str.substring(fi, li)
}
```